# PDO Insert to table postgres

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

I'm trying to insert something to Postgres table, however I try it always fail to insert values and not even display any error.

My try looks like:

```
public function insertToTable($code, $name)
{
    echo "code: ".$code."name:".$name;  
    try {                
        $con = new PDO( DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS ); 
        $con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
        echo "OK CONN OPEN";
        $sql = "INSERT INTO r_vehicle_manufacturer(code, name) VALUES(:code, :name)";
        echo "OK INSERT";
        $stmt = $con->prepare( $sql );
        $stmt->bindValue( "code", $code, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
        $stmt->bindValue( "name", $name, PDO::PARAM_STR );                
        $stmt->execute();                
        }
    catch( PDOException $e ) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }           
}
```

Where DB info are defined on TOP of FILE:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
define( "DB_HOST", "pgsql:host=IP:PORT;dbname=name;charset=utf8" );    
define( "DB_USER", "user" );
define( "DB_PASS", "pass" );
```

I try to debug this and insert multiple "echo" if values are there and so on,
it echo values before `$con` but nothing else, so please any advise?

EDIT:
Tested manualy add via Postgress console:

```
INSERT INTO r_vehicle_manufacturer (code, name)
    VALUES ('00', 'AUDI');
```

without any problem

Comment: which part you mean? in definition? OR bindValue?

Comment: script dont even get to this PART :), I am thinking if there can not be problem that table have foreign key from other table.

Comment: `$stmt->bindValue( "code", $code, PDO::PARAM_STR );` -> see the `"code"`, first argument to `bindValue()`? It **must**  begin with a colon character, meaning `":code"` is the proper way to specify the parameter.

Comment: Hi @N.B. I know what you mean but it actualy doesn't have to. I think it was changed in past :)

Comment: Have you checked if it's going into the `catch` clause? You appear to be *returning* the exception message, so is that value actually echoed anywhere? Maybe `echo $e;` would be more useful while debugging.

Comment: actualy @IMSoP comment helped, I fix this after some time. There were multiple problems there  ( disabled PDO_PG library and problems with foreign keys in DB'